# Programmatically Setting UINavigation Bar Button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

How can I set the UINavigation Bar Button to a particular image programmatically using Swift?[image]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       let rightButton: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) 
       rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40) ; 
       rightButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"ImageName.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
       rightButton.addTarget(self, action: "rightNavButtonClick:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

       var rightBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightButton)

       self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(rightBarButtonItem, animated: false);
```

Try this this should work!!

Comment: How can I make it be the right bar button item? Because currently its the left one?

Comment: self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(rightBarButtonItem, animated: false); replace this code with last line.